# How to call a function ones and never compute again in python?

Tags: python, serialization, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I have a function F() witch take lot of time but always return the same result.

I would like to be able to skip this call and get directly the result next time I launch my program.

How to do that?

Comment: Cache the result. Likely by writing it to a file and then reading again from it.

Comment: If it *always* returns the same result, you could just hard code the value instead of the actual implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write the results to a file. Which file depends on what the outcome of your function is.

One option would be to write as a pickle.

```
import pickle
result = F()

with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as pfile:
    pickle.dump(result, pfile)
```

next time you can get the result with this code instead of running your function F()

```
with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as pfile:
    result = pickle.load(pfile)
```